# three.js : Disable perspective on one axis

Tags: three.js, 3d

I want a special effect which is not realistic.

When I render a mesh, I do not want the rendering to be affected on the Y axis. Which means that for a specific column, the perspective has to be the same. So the perspective is affected only by the (x, z) positions.

Do you think it's possible?

Comment: I don't know three.js but I know openGL, could you have two matrices: one with perspective, one without. Then to get multiply (x,y,z,1) by both matrices and cnstruct your final vector taking the result for x and y from one matrix and y from the other?

Comment: so the one without would be only the modelView Matrix ?

Comment: yes that's the way I see it. I can't promise it will give good results but it's worth a try.

Comment: I just tried that. But the results are not what I expected  ... My object is being squeezed on the y-axis :/ What I want is the way the orthographic camera would have render it but only one one axis. But thanks for the idea !

Comment: then maybe instead of just ModelView, do ModelView Projection but with orthogonal projection?

Comment: I think it can be a solution but it complicated to do that in three.js since it's a high level libray. I have to modify the library. I think that the only solution so I am going to try that. Thanks for your advices !

Comment: Cool problem. Just a thought: if the frustum of an orthographic camera is a cuboid, and the frustum of a perspective camera is a pyramid, you’re trying to make a wedge. Pretty sure that’s a valid matrix, and you can replace your camera’s `projectionMatrix` with that.

Comment: Did any of this ever worked, could you show the code?

Comment: unfortunately i didn't find the solution yet ... I had to stop looking. i'm getting back on this problem right now. I'll let you know if i find the solution. If anyone has others ideas, don't hesitate :)

Comment: I just posted a first solution (a quick hack actually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hack I did quickly as POC is to change a line in three.js.

I replaced this line :

```
var project_vertex = `"vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );\ngl_Position = (projectionMatrix * mvPosition);";`
```

by :

`var project_vertex = "vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );\ngl_Position = (projectionMatrix * mvPosition);\ngl_Position.y = gl_Position.y*gl_Position.w;";`

This answer [How to draw ortho axes for object in perspective projection using modern OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918798/how-to-draw-ortho-axes-for-object-in-perspective-projection-using-modern-opengl), which explains that multiplying a coordinate by the last component w removes the perspective, helped me.

Now I have to find a proper way to do that which integrate properly with three.js and will work for any axis we want to disable the perspective.

**UPDATE**

One way to do that without having to modify three.js :

```
//As stated here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918798/how-to-draw-ortho-axes-for-object-in-perspective-projection-using-modern-opengl
// In order to remove the perspective in one axis, you have to muliply by the 4th component of gl_position (w)
var project_vertex_custom = "vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );\ngl_Position = (projectionMatrix * mvPosition);"
if (disablePerspectiveAxis.indexOf("x") >= 0)
    project_vertex_custom += "\ngl_Position.x = gl_Position.x*gl_Position.w;";
if(disablePerspectiveAxis.indexOf("y") >= 0)
    project_vertex_custom += "\ngl_Position.y = gl_Position.y*gl_Position.w;";

//Update the glsl code in three.js
THREE.ShaderChunk.project_vertex = project_vertex_custom;
```

Comment: This answer is gold ! there should be a math article about this.